# No module named urls in django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I just copy paste tastypie sample code to get know how it works. The code is as follows.
I have made modelclass Entry also. When i run http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ on url it throws error

```
# myapp/api/resources.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from myapp.models import Entry


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        filtering = {
        'username': ALL,
    }


class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

class Meta:
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'entry'
    authorization = Authorization()
    filtering = {
        'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        'pub_date': ['exact', 'lt', 'lte', 'gte', 'gt'],
    }
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from tastypie.api import Api
from myapp.api.resources import EntryResource, UserResource

v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())
v1_api.register(EntryResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # The normal jazz here...
    (r'^blog/', include('myapp.urls')),
    (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
 )
```

It is throwing message "No module named urls" . Any ideas?

Comment: You need to include the traceback. Its ambiguous as to where this error is even being raised. My guess is its the `v1_api.urls`?

Comment: You've missed quotes in "include(v1_api.urls)"

Comment: where your error line number showing?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
(r'^api/', include('v1_api.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is shwing because there is no module named urls.py in myapp package. create a module urls.py in myapp package

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`from django.conf.urls.defaults import *`

You can try import like this

```
from django.conf.urls import *
```