# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tastypie'

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie, modulenotfounderror

I am new to Django and coding in general.

When I try to use the django-tastypie (0.14.4) in my virtual env using pipenv, I get the following error when I try to launch the server ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tastypie'.

I tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605127/modulenotfound-error-in-django-in-django-tastypie-web-application) and in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607362/importerror-no-module-named-tastypie-api)

Here is my models.py of my api app:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from movies.models import Movie 

class MovieResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Movie.objects.all()  
        resource_name= "movies" 
        excludes = ["date_created"]
```

and my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,  include
from api.models import MovieResource

movie_resource = MovieResource()


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("movies/",include("movies.urls")),
    path("api/",include(movie_resource.urls))
```

and the full error:

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10e6d9090>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/sylvainkreuter/vidly1/api/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tastypie'
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named tastypie.api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607362/importerror-no-module-named-tastypie-api)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: But does your IDE detects that you have tastypie installed?

Comment: It shows as installed dependencies when I run ```pipenv run pip freeze``` if that's what you mean

Comment: Add `tastypie` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

confirm if you have installed django-tastypie in your virtual environment by: pipenv graph

and enable the virtual environment using: pipenv shell

now try to run your command.....